# PEP 0492 - Python 3.5 async keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, coroutine

[PEP 0492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) adds the `async` keyword to Python 3.5.

How does Python benefit from the use of this operator? The example that is given for a coroutine is

```
async def read_data(db):
    data = await db.fetch('SELECT ...')
```

According to the docs this achieves

> suspend[ing] execution of read_data coroutine until db.fetch awaitable completes and returns the result data.

Does this `async` keyword actually involve creation of new threads or perhaps the use of an existing reserved async thread?

In the event that `async` does use a reserved thread, is it a single shared thread each in their own?

Comment: Co-routines do not use threads.

Comment: So in this case, how does Python achieve any benefit out of suspending executions in comparison to a generator?

Comment: Note that the PEP only aims to make certain patterns easier to code; no new functionality is introduced with the syntax. Co-routines *cooperate* in that they allow switching between tasks at pre-defined points (rather than threads which switch execution between different units at arbitrary points).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No, co-routines do not involve any kind of threads. Co-routines allow for *cooperative* multi-tasking in that each co-routine yields control voluntarily. Threads on the other hand switch between units at arbitrary points.

Up to Python 3.4, it was possible to write co-routines using *generators*; by using `yield` or `yield from` expressions in a function body you create a generator object instead, where code is only executed when you iterate over the generator. Together with additional event loop libraries (such as [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)) you could write co-routines that would signal to an event loop that they were going to be busy (waiting for I/O perhaps) and that another co-routine could be run in the meantime:

```
import asyncio
import datetime

@asyncio.coroutine
def display_date(loop):
    end_time = loop.time() + 5.0
    while True:
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        if (loop.time() + 1.0) >= end_time:
            break
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Every time the above code advances to the `yield from asyncio.sleep(1)` line, the event loop is free to run a different co-routine, because this routine is not going to do anything for the next second *anyway*.

Because generators can be used for all sorts of tasks, not just co-routines, and because writing a co-routine using generator syntax can be confusing to new-comers, the PEP introduces new syntax that makes it *clearer* that you are writing a co-routine.

With the PEP implemented, the above sample could be written instead as:

```
async def display_date(loop):
    end_time = loop.time() + 5.0
    while True:
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        if (loop.time() + 1.0) >= end_time:
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

The resulting *`coroutine`* object still needs an event loop to drive the co-routines; an event loop would `await` on each co-routine in turn, which would execute those co-routines that are not currently `await`ing for something to complete.

The advantages are that with native support, you can also introduce additional syntax to support asynchronous context managers and iterators. Entering and exiting a context manager, or looping over an iterator then can become more points in your co-routine that signal that other code can run instead because something is waiting again.

Comment: Any case there's a proper motivation behind not implementing async generators based on AsyncInterator as part of built-in syntax with yields?

Comment: That's something you'll need to discuss on the Python-ideas list, SO comments are not a good medium for that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm having a hard time understanding asyncio, still. Given your example, the output is something like `2016-03-04 11:53:48.282701` with a new printed line every 1 second. Wouldn't that mean your program is hung up while `await`-ing? I was expecting to see a 1 second delay upon running it, and then a stream of printed datetimes, since the `await asyncio.sleep(...)` should yield as soon as it realizes it has to wait for "io" (in this case, sleep). IOW, the `while` loop would continue running quickly, while the `await`s would eventually catch up. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: @orokusaki: the `await asyncio.sleep(1)` line **immediately** yields as *I'm busy, someone else do something*, each time you tried to advance this co-routine, until a full second has passed. It never *blocks*, it just insta-yields with a special 'waiting' message. Because it doesn't block, the co-routine event loop (which polls all the co-routines to find one that is *not* busy waiting) can run a different co-routine. It can 'poll' this co-routine as often as it likes, but that `await` line won't continue the rest of the code until the 1 second time has passed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the quick reply. Ah, so in this case, the coroutine as a whole (including the loop) is in a 'waiting' state, which means it isn't blocking, but if I wanted to achieve something like I've stated (pretending that asyncio.sleep(1) is equivalent to 1 second of Postgres IO), it would need to set up such that the coroutine is run once per action? IOW, I run the line `loop.run_until_complete(query('SELECT ...'))` 10 times, and assuming the query takes about 1 second, I would see the results of all 10 of them in just over 1 second?

Comment: @orokusaki: a proper awaitable takes care of these details for you; e.g. will in turn poll for results from PostgreSQL and unblock with a 'waiting' signal if no results are available yet. The PEP also defines [awaitable iterators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-iterators-and-async-for) which are ideal for SQL queries where there may be I/O delays between results; the iterable then 'awaits' for those results, unblocking in between.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again @MartijnPieters