# Why would I ever want to use `async def` over `@asyncio.coroutine`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, backwards-compatibility

Python 3.5 greatly expanded support for asynchronous programming with a new function definition syntax. Whereas async functions were previously just "generators with benefits":

```
def generate_numbers():
    """
    Generator function that lazily returns 1 - 100
    """
    for i in range 100:
        yield i

generate_async = asyncio.coroutine(generate_numbers)
generate_async.__doc__ = """
    Coroutine that lazily returns 1 - 100
    This can be used interchangeably as a generator or a coroutine
    """
```

they now have their own special declaration syntax and special behavior by which they are no longer usable as usual generator functions:

```
aysnc def generate_async_native():
    """
    A coroutine that returns 1 - 100
    This CANNOT be used as a generator, and can ONLY be executed by running it from an event loop
    """
    for i in range(100):
        await i
```

This is ***not*** a question about the functional or practical differences between these types -- that is discussed in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40573425/2954547).

My question is: why would I ever want to use `async def`? It seems like it provides no additional benefit over `@asyncio.coroutine`, but imposes an additional cost in that it

1. breaks backward-compatibility (Python 3.5 code with `async def`
   won't even *parse* in older versions, although this is arguably a feature and not a bug) and
2. seems to provide less flexibility in how the function can be called.

Comment: I removed the `syntax` tag and added the `python` one. In general, you should add the python tag to all python questions since that is the tag that most people keep track of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible answer is given by [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31291832/2954547):

> The advantages are that with native support, you can also introduce additional syntax to support asynchronous context managers and iterators. Entering and exiting a context manager, or looping over an iterator then can become more points in your co-routine that signal that other code can run instead because something is waiting again

This has in fact come to fruition with new `async with` and `async for` syntax, which cannot be as easily implemented with a "tack-on" solution like a decorated generator.