# What does the "yield from" syntax do in asyncio and how is it different from "await"

Tags: python, async-await, generator, python-asyncio, coroutine

From the perspective of someone who has written asyncio code but is looking to better understand the inner workings, what is `yield from`, `await` and how are those useful for allowing asynchronous code?

There is one [highly upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3) question asking about the uses of the `yield from` syntax and [one explaining async and await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291129/pep-0492-python-3-5-async-keyword), but both go in depth about different topics and are not really a concise explanation of the underlying code and how it fits in with asyncio.

Comment: It seems like the second question that you've linked gives a pretty straight forward explanation of how `async` and `await` can be used to more succinctly express what you used to need `yield from` & `asyncio.coroutine` to express.  I guess I'm not really sure what the question is asking since that example seems to explain it pretty well.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @mgilson it goes into how `await` relates to `yield from` but not actually what `yield from` does

Comment: They're the same, except `await` is more [recent](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) and looks much better

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**Short answer:**

`yield from` is an old way to wait for asyncio's coroutine.

`await` is a modern way to wait for asyncio's coroutine.

**Detailed answer:**

Python has generators - special kind of functions that produces a sequence of results instead of a single value. Starting with Python 3.3 `yield from` expression was added. It [allows](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) one generator to delegate part of its operations to another generator.

Starting with Python 3.4 `asyncio` module was added to standard library. It allow us to write clear and understandable asynchronous code. While technically asyncio's coroutines could be implemented different ways, in `asyncio` they were implemented using generators (you can watch for [excellent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) where shown how generators can be used to implement coroutines). `@asyncio.coroutine` was a way to make coroutine from generator and `yield from` was a way to await for coroutine - just details of implementation.

That's how happened that `yield from` started to be used for two "different things".

Starting with Python 3.5 (see [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/)) coroutines got new syntax. Now you can define coroutine with `async def` and await for it using `await` expression. It's not only shorter to write, but also makes clearer to understand that we work with asyncio's coroutines.

If you're using Python 3.5+ you can forget about using `yield from` for asyncio's coroutines and use `await` for it.

Comment: Holy c**p, @mikhail, I wish I had read this before wasting so much of my time with `yield from` and `@asyncio.coroutine`!  Then I read `async def` and `await`, and I went "ummmm, I wonder what's the difference".  I wish this were made clearer in [PEP 3156](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156)...

Comment: Thanks. "except generators" should maybe be a little more explicit, you are technically correct that an instance of `def foo(): x = yield` is of type `generator` (for historic reasons), but colloquially it's a "[Beazly-style](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/)" coroutine and not really what people think of when saying generator.

Comment: @timgeb thanks, corrected. I think now should be ok :)

Comment: I personally think this is the most confusing questions/documents in whole Python history. With "async def" and "await", it gets 10x better but still, it's the most confusing feature for Python. I don't get how they even make "yield from" officiallly released... If I were to learn a new language now, I would skip Python just because of this syntax.

Comment: I understand that `await` actually allows Python to do other stuff while the awaited task is in progress. Is this the case with `yield from` as well? It feels like `yield from` is blocking (presumably because it's just a chain of `yield`s)

Comment: @Jay `await` (as well as its old version `yield from`) will "block" local execution flow without blocking event loop. To run task without blocking local execution flow, you need to create asyncio's task - [read about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345564/1113207).