# Is `asyncio.sleep(delay)` guarenteed to sleep for at least `delay` seconds?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

`asyncio.sleep()`'s blocking cousin, [time.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep), cannot guarantee that it will sleep for the requested amount of time.

> The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine.

`asyncio.sleep()`'s [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping) does not mention a similar limitation.

Is `asyncio.sleep()` able to make stronger guarantees about the amount of time it will sleep for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will not tell what `asyncio` *guarantees*, but based on the implementation it follows that the `asyncio.sleep()`(basically, `call_later()`) sleeps for the specified interval, **but at least with an inaccuracy equal to the resolution of the system clock** used in the implementation.

Let's figure it out. First, `asyncio` uses monotonic clocks, which have different resolutions [on different platforms](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/#monotonic-clocks) (both Python and OS resolutions). For example, for `Windows` this is as much as `15ms`.

In terms of guarantees, pay attention to the comment to the function `BaseEventLoop.time`:

```
    def time(self):
        """Return the time according to the event loop's clock.
        This is a float expressed in seconds since an epoch, but the
        epoch, precision, accuracy and drift are unspecified and may
        differ per event loop.
        """
        return time.monotonic()
```

Now let's take a look at the `asyncio` event loop source [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py) responsible for starting the scheduled timers:

```
        # Handle 'later' callbacks that are ready.
        end_time = self.time() + self._clock_resolution
        while self._scheduled:
            handle = self._scheduled[0]
            if handle._when >= end_time:
                break
            handle = heapq.heappop(self._scheduled)
            handle._scheduled = False
            self._ready.append(handle)
```

Line `end_time = self.time() + self._clock_resolution` shows that the callback **may fire earlier** than planned but within the clock resolution. Yuri Selivanov clearly stated about this [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue31539):

> As I see it, currently we peek into the future time.  Why don't we do
>
> ```
>        end_time = self.time() - self._clock_resolution
> ```
>
> to guarantee that timeouts will always be triggered *after* the requested time, not before?  I don't see how the performance can become worse if we do this.

And really, let's run the next program (Python 3.8 on Windows 10):

```
import asyncio 
import time

async def main():
    print("Timer resolution", time.get_clock_info('monotonic').resolution)
    while True:
        asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(1))

        t0 = time.monotonic()
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        t1 = time.monotonic()

        print(t1 - t0)
asyncio.run(main())
```

We see behaviour described above:

```
Timer resolution 0.015625
0.09299999987706542
0.0940000000409782
0.0940000000409782
0.10900000017136335
...
```

But at the beginning of the text, I said **at least the clock resolution**, because `asyncio` works in conditions of cooperative multitasking, and if there is a greedy coroutine (or many less greedy ones) that does not give control to the event loop too often, we have the following picture:

```
import asyncio 
import time

async def calc():
    while True:
        k = 0
        for i in range(1*10**6):        
            k += i
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # yield to event loop
    

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(calc())  # start greedy coroutine
    print("Timer resolution", time.get_clock_info('monotonic').resolution)
    while True:
        asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(1))

        t0 = time.monotonic()
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        t1 = time.monotonic()

        print(t1 - t0)
asyncio.run(main())
```

The situation is unsurprisingly changing towards increasing latency:

```
0.17200000025331974
0.1559999999590218
0.14100000029429793
0.2190000000409782
```