# Asyncio loop.call_later timing accuracy

Tags: python, python-asyncio, event-loop

- I am trying to have a function run periodically on the event loop
- It is vital for the function to be called at the rate specified
- I'm recursively scheduling the function to run using `asyncio.call_later`
- It appears that `asyncio.call_later` does not call the function with the correct delay
- The timer handle returned by `call_later` confirms that the delay is greater than expected

**Why is the function not being called at the specified rate?**

```py
import asyncio
import time

def print_fps():
    global last_time

    time_now = time.time()
    dt = time_now - last_time
    if dt > 0:
        print(f"fps: {round(1/dt, 3)} [{round(dt,3)}s], target: {fps} [{round(1/fps,3)}s]")
    else:
        print("dt = 0")
    last_time = time_now

def loop_func():
    # print fps info
    print_fps()

    # schedule next iteration of loop
    loop.call_later(1/fps, loop_func)

async def main():
    loop_func()

last_time = time.time()
fps = 60

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

Output:

```
fps: 31.446 [0.032s], target: 60 [0.017s]
fps: 32.693 [0.031s], target: 60 [0.017s]
fps: 32.172 [0.031s], target: 60 [0.017s]
fps: 31.663 [0.032s], target: 60 [0.017s]
fps: 32.001 [0.031s], target: 60 [0.017s]
fps: 30.549 [0.033s], target: 60 [0.017s]
fps: 34.486 [0.029s], target: 60 [0.017s]
fps: 31.366 [0.032s], target: 60 [0.017s]
fps: 31.743 [0.032s], target: 60 [0.017s]
fps: 30.057 [0.033s], target: 60 [0.017s]
```

[cProfile reveals nothing is blocking the event loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVX6m.png)

Comment: It might be due to system clock resolution. Related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65715878/is-asyncio-sleepdelay-guarenteed-to-sleep-for-at-least-delay-seconds/65727201#65727201)

Comment: @alex_noname You're dead on. Sleep interval is set by the system, which was in this case Windows with about 15ms minimum sleep period. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, doesn't running a function (print_fps in this case) and scheduling the next call within the current call introduce a drift? ideally you would not want to wait for any logic, not a function call nor the function that schedules for the next call, to schedule the next call, as it would mean that your time between wake ups is not the interval that you specify to `.call_later` but rather that interval plus a small constant.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while looking for a way to make asyncio.sleep accurate on windows, where it defaults to 16ms accuracy. I developed a solution so I'm putting it here in case anyone else, looking for the same thing as me, makes their way here - sorry it's not quite specific to your question.

Here is an accurate sleep function that works with asyncio on Windows - you might need to modify the delay time on other platforms:

```
import sys
import asyncio
import time

async def accurate_sleep(s):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    if s > 0.016: # 16ms for windows sleep accuracy
        await asyncio.sleep(s - 0.016)
    while (time.perf_counter() - start) < s:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


async def sleep_test():
    samples = 50
    err = 0.0
    maxerr = 0
    for i in range(0, samples):
        start_ns = time.perf_counter_ns()
        await asyncio.sleep(i * 0.001)
        result_us = (time.perf_counter_ns() - start_ns) // 1_000
        # print("    " + str(i) + " ms\t" + str(result_ms - i) + " ms err")
        err += abs(result_us - i * 1000)
        maxerr = max(maxerr, abs(result_us - i * 1000))

    ferr = 0.0
    fmaxerr = 0
    for i in range(0, samples):
        start_ns = time.perf_counter_ns()
        await accurate_sleep(i * 0.001)
        result_us = (time.perf_counter_ns() - start_ns) // 1_000
        # print("    " + str(i) + " ms\t" + str(result_ms - i) + " ms err")
        ferr += abs(result_us - i * 1000)
        fmaxerr = max(fmaxerr, abs(result_us - i * 1000))

    print(
        "  Basic asyncio sleep err avg "
        + str(err / samples)
        + " us, max err "
        + str(maxerr)
        + " us"
    )
    print(
        "  Fancy Asyncio sleep err avg "
        + str(ferr / samples)
        + " us, max err "
        + str(fmaxerr)
        + " us"
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(sleep_test())
```

Test results on my Win 11 box:

> Basic asyncio sleep err avg 8215.12 us, max err 16463 us

> Fancy Asyncio sleep err avg 1.8 us, max err 4 us