# Python coroutine/generator terminology in async context

Tags: python, async-await, generator, python-asyncio, coroutine

From the web, it says

> When you have an asynchronous function (coroutine) in Python, you declare it with async def, which changes how its call behaves. In particular, calling it will immediately return a coroutine object, which basically says "I can run the coroutine with the arguments you called with and return a result when you await me"

**So when you call an `async` function without await, you will get back a coroutine.**

Why I get back a coroutine, why not just a **generator**? Because I'm not sending any future input to it.

Comment: It's defined better in [PEP 3156](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/#coroutines).

Comment: The confusing part is that the word coroutine is now used for two related but distinct concepts: one are the bidirectional generators defined in PEP 342, and the other are async functions defined in PEP 492. Calling an async function without awaiting it gives you a PEP 492 coroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When coroutines first appeared in Python 3.4 they were implemented using generators:

```
import asyncio
from typing import Generator


@asyncio.coroutine
def test1():
    pass


assert isinstance(test1(), Generator)
```

It wasn't because coroutines always should be generators, it just happened they were: it was the most convenient way to implement them.

---

Starting with Python 3.5 [coroutines got their new syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273861/1113207) `async def`/`await` which both cleaner and also helps to distinguish abstraction (coroutine) from its implementation detail (generator).

It seems that new-style coroutines were also patched to show that they shouldn't be treated like generators:

```
async def test2():
    pass


assert not isinstance(test2(), Generator)
```

---

So long story short: forget about generators when deal with coroutines. If you work with asyncio's abstractions like coroutines you should work with them rather than with their implementation details.