# await vs yield from for python

Tags: python, async-await

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273861/433570
says 'yield from' is old and we should learn 'await'.
But It doesn't say they are the same thing or they are different.

But I have some good book and videos which talks about `yield from`

Can I think `yield from` was replaced by `await`? and they are essentially the same thing?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4

I have a book `fluent python` which also talks about `yield from`

- Edit

When I see some good books/videos like the above talking about `yield from`, could I substitute `yield from` with `await` in my mind?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "yield from" syntax do in asyncio and how is it different from "await"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251045/what-does-the-yield-from-syntax-do-in-asyncio-and-how-is-it-different-from-aw)

Comment: @testfile I even quoted the link in my op. It doesn't clearly say they are the same thing 
whether I can think of `await` as a new name for `yield from`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are the same thing. Yield is the manual way of doing async await. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#new-coroutine-declaration-syntax where they detail that async await is just a coroutine (yield) underneath

Comment: `yield` and `await` may be similar under the hood, but they aren't the same thing, and they're not interchangeable. I had code that wasn't working with `await`, I replaced `await` with `yield` and suddenly the code worked fine. I'm not sure why just that change fixed it, but it has me certain that they aren't "the same thing".